# Can ElasticSearch "explain" search option be used for all requests but not for debugging?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to retrieve information about what exact terms match the search query.

I found out that this problem was discussed in the following topic: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17045
but was not resolved "**since it would be too cumbersome and expensive to keep this information around**" (inside of ElasticSearch context).

Then I discovered that using "explain" option in search request I get the detailed information about score calculation including matching terms.

I made some kind of performance test to compare search requests with explain option set to true and without explain option. And this test doesn't show significant impact of explain option usage.

So I'm wondering if this option can be used for production system? It looks like some kind of workaround but seems it's working.

Any considerations about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you didn't include the details of your performance test, so it's really difficult to know and say whether it would make a performance impact or not and again it's relative to:

1. What is your cluster configuration, total nodes, size, shards, replicas, JVM, no of documents, size of documents?
2. Index configuration ie, for which index you are using the explain API, again is it a ready or write-heavy index, how many docs, during peak time how it performs, etc.

Apart from that, in An application, **there will be only certain types of queries although search term might change, the underlying concept of whether it matches or not them can be understood by samples itself**.

I've worked with search systems extensively and I use **explain API** a lot but only on samples and not on all queries and have not seen this happening anywhere.

**EDIT:- Please have a look at [named queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html) which can also be used to check which part of your queries matched the search results and more info on [this official blog](https://qbox.io/blog/elasticsearch-named-queries.)**

Comment: Thank you for response! My test is run on 3 nodes cluster, each node contains 50gb of data, ~180 mln of documents. Replicas: 2, shards: 3. Machine m4.2xlarge: 32Gb RAM (4g for elasticsearch process), 8cpu, disk 300gb.
Java: open jdk 1.8
Test performs fuzzy search (only search) request with 80 RPS. 
For test without explain the mean latency is about 190ms, with explain - about 230 ms. So delta ~40 ms.

Comment: @katrin, which version of elasticsearch u r using? and I can see a lot of improvement in your cluster configuration which would be out of scope for this question and difficult to explain on a question, but to just give you an idea, you should allocate at least 50% of your RAM for elasticsearch process and it shouldn't exceed more than 30 Gb for better GC, so can you increase your elastic process to 16 GB and again run these tests?

Comment: Thank you for idea with the named queries, looks good, I'll try it.

Comment: ElasticSearch version is 6.7.2. 
Probably more heap can be well for read-only/rarely write cluster. But for my write-profiles I see the problems when the RAM is 8 or 16, the profile with 4g heap shows better results.

Comment: @katrin, you can increase the refresh interval(default 1 sec) if your requirements are not NRT search to reduce the pressure

Comment: the refresh interval is currently set to 15s in my profile

Comment: thank you for useful discussion. But.. still wondering if the "explain" option is considered for debugging purposes only? I didn't find direct recommendations from ElasticSearch and any performance concerns in the documentation of "explain". Is it really a weird idea to use it for all requests?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210597/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-katrin).